# How to make fix height on items in GridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm making some grid with image and text, using GridLayoutManager. But currently my items have different height if on one row text is on one line and on the second row text has two lines, which don't looks good. How to make all items equals to each other (best option if every item height will be equal to max element height

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            tools:text="Long title long title long title(560)" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"` in your textview

Comment: Another option is estimate max lines needed, and set in the TextView's android:lines="3" for example, then all are 3 lines.

Comment: you can set minLines = 2 , so even if text of one line would take size as per two lines so it will match with the two liners textviews.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code may work for you, where I have created custom relative layout

```
package com.test;

public class MySquareRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public MySquareRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MySquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MySquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MySquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Set a square layout.
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.test.MySquareRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/elementRootView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            tools:text="Long title long title long title(560)" />

</com.test.MySquareRelativeLayout>
```